# T-SQL DENSE_RANK() is not returning what I expect

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having trouble getting the DENSE_RANK() (or similar) to get the values I want from a select query.  I have tried RANK() and ROW_NUMBER() and I have changed the PARTITION and ORDER-BY fields but no luck.
The query follows...

```
SELECT         100 * DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY UID_CUSTOMER, INT_GROUP_BY ORDER BY UID_CUSTOMER) AS  aINT_GROUP_BY,                
                 5 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UID_DIVISION, UID_CUSTOMER,INT_GROUP_BY ORDER BY UID_DIVISION, UID_CUSTOMER, INT_GROUP_BY, INT_SORT_ORDER) AS  aINT_SORT_ORDER,                
               UID_DIVISION, UID_CUSTOMER, UID_VEHICLE, INT_GROUP_BY, TXT_GROUP_NAME
FROM           tVEHICLES TV
ORDER BY       UID_DIVISION, UID_CUSTOMER, INT_GROUP_BY, INT_SORT_ORDER;
```

I show the result with an offset of the UID_CUSTOMER-number so you can see three different customers are listed (Column captions are changed to narrow the list display).

```
aGROUP_BY  aSORT_ORDER  UID_DIVISION  UID_CUSTOMER  GROUP_BY  TXT_GROUP_NAME
100        5            5             82            100       Group-100
100        10           5             82            100       Group-100
100        15           5             82            100       Group-100
100        20           5             82            100       Group-100
100        25           5             82            100       Group-100
100        5            5             86            100       Group-100
100        10           5             86            100       Group-100
100        15           5             86            100       Group-100
100        20           5             86            100       Group-100
100        25           5             86            100       Group-100
100        30           5             86            100       Group-100
100        5            5             88            100       North
100        10           5             88            100       North
100        15           5             88            100       North
100        5            5             88            200       South
100        10           5             88            200       South
100        15           5             88            200       South
```

The two columns shown are derived from the OVER-constructs and I expected the aGROUP_BY value to be 200 not 100.  The source of the field-data are in the remaining columns 3 to 6.

Your comments and advice is very welcome...John

Comment: Why did you expect it to be anything other that 1 * 100? It looks like you are partitioning by all unique fields, which means that each row is alone in each partition. What *do* you want to return? In which grouping would the 17th row be the first or second?

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos .  I am not sure what your comment means, relative to partitioning all fields.  I see UID_CUSTOMER and INT_GROUP_BY partitioning.  I am not advanced in the RANK...OVER...construct, so I may need some help -- to make items 15,16,17 become 200 not 100.  Thanks.

Comment: Please clean up the query and data, remove unused fields and make sure you use the same names. It's impossible to discern *which* fields you want, and which ones you actually partition by. Remove *all* superflous prefixes like `INT_`, they don't serve any purpose other than making the query hard to read.

Comment: Also add a table creation statement and add test data. Don't force people to do that just to try and get the same results. Especially when the results don't match the query itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos --  I will proceed with your suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY UID_CUSTOMER, INT_GROUP_BY ORDER BY UID_CUSTOMER) AS  aINT_GROUP_BY,
```

You've got the rank partitioned by two fields: customer and 'INT_GROUP_BY' -- so the rows 13 thru 17 in your data set actually contain two partitions.  the first is 88,100 and the second is 88,200.  The ranking in each group starts at 1, which is why you are seeing 100 in all six rows.

Modify your code to this:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY UID_CUSTOMER ORDER BY UID_CUSTOMER, INT_GROUP_BY) AS  aINT_GROUP_BY,
```

Where INT_GROUP_BY is in the order clause and not the partition clause, and you should see your expected behavior.

Comment: EXCELLENT -- this is the answer.  You are very smart.  You showed us how to "look at" the relationships of the PARTITION and the ORDER-BY sections of the construct like this.  Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UID_DIVISION, UID_CUSTOMER, INT_GROUP_BY, INT_SORT_ORDER)  AS  aRowNumber, 
         100 * DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY INT_GROUP_BY 
                                  ORDER BY UID_CUSTOMER
                                 ) AS  aINT_GROUP_BY,                
         5 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UID_DIVISION, INT_GROUP_BY  
                                ORDER BY UID_CUSTOMER, INT_SORT_ORDER
                               ) AS  aINT_SORT_ORDER,                
         UID_DIVISION, UID_CUSTOMER, UID_VEHICLE, INT_GROUP_BY, INT_SORT_ORDER, TXT_GROUP_NAME
FROM      tVEHICLES TV
ORDER BY  UID_DIVISION, UID_CUSTOMER, INT_GROUP_BY, INT_SORT_ORDER;
```